# Können „und zwar“ und „nämlich“ am Anfang des Satzes stehen?

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunction, style

Kann man in der *Standardhochsprache* den neuen Satz, der sich auf den vorigen Text bezieht bedenkenlos mit *und zwar* oder dem Wort *nämlich* einleiten? Zum Beispiel:

> Laut einem Artikel gebe es erneut Probleme wenn man das Betriebssystem auf den neuen Stand bringen wolle. *Und zwar* soll es einen gravierenden Fehler geben, der …

Könnte man das Wort *nämlich/ namentlich* auch auf die gleiche Weise verwenden, und es auf den Anfang des Satzes schieben? Zum Beispiel:

> Laut einem Artikel gebe es erneut Probleme wenn man das Betriebssystem auf den neuen Stand bringen wolle. *Nämlich* soll es einen gravierenden Fehler geben, der …

Comment: Selbst bei einem alleinigen und sehe ich da absolut kein Problem. *Heute bleibe ich zuhause. Und morgen auch.*

Comment: Der so entstehende Satz ist kein Satz nach dem Standardmodell. Man kann solche Sätze bilden, und sie können als wohlgeformt gelten, aber man muss ein gutes Gespür dafür haben, wo und wie man sie einsetzen kann.

Comment: Heh, hab' noch nie die Verwendung von "nämlich" gerade am Anfang gesehen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sicher kann man das. Stilistisch finde ich weder das eine noch das andere optimal, weil beides im Grunde überflüssig ist.

> Laut einem Artikel gebe es erneut Probleme wenn man das Betriebssystem auf den neuen Stand bringen wolle. Es soll einen gravierenden Fehler geben, der …

reicht völlig.

Ohne dass ich das statistisch belegen möchte, wird meiner Erfahrung nach *nämlich* in der Regel eher für die Angabe von Gründen verwendet.

> Es kann gar nicht sein, dass du mich in Berlin gesehen hast. Ich war nämlich zu dieser Zeit in Hamburg.

Für falsch halte ich die Verwendung wie in der Frage trotzdem nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ja.

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach:

- Je "flüchtiger" der Text, desto eher passt es.

  - d.h., ein Text wird als weniger dauerhaft und damit "flüchtig" angesehen, je informeller er ist.
  - d.h., dass digitale Kommunikation dazu neigt, als informell und wenig dauerhaft wahrgenommen zu werden, dies steigt je kürzer die üblichen Texte des jeweiligen Kommunikationskanals sind: für manche ist E-Mail wie ein (Papier-)Brief, für andere wie Twitter.<sup>und in Zeitungen abgedruckte Tweets werden plötzlich dauerhaft</sup>

Die Beispiele würde ich unter Beibehaltung  der Struktur so schreiben:

> Laut einem Artikel gebe es erneut Probleme wenn man das Betriebssystem auf den neuen Stand bringen wolle. Es soll einen gravierenden Fehler geben, der …
>
> Laut einem Artikel gebe es erneut Probleme wenn man das Betriebssystem auf den neuen Stand bringen wolle. Es soll nämlich einen gravierenden Fehler geben, der …

Andere Beispiele, wo der gefragte Satzanfang besser passt:

> Es gibt Probleme beim Surfen im Internet. Nämlich mit dem kaputten Update.
>
> Das Fenster geht auf. Und zwar sobald man vorher die Scheibe putzt.

Comment: Statt "mündlich" oder "digital" zu verwenden, die ja offensichtlich beide nicht passen, würde ich vorschlagen von "flüchtiger Kommunikation" zu sprechen oder von Umgangssprache. Bei den 2 letzten Beispielen sehe ich aber keinen Grund, einmal ein Komma zu verwenden, einmal den Punkt einfach wegzulassen.

Comment: @userunknown: danke für den Hinweis mit der Begrifflichkeit. Die Beispielsätze - ich mir fiel keiner ein, der generell und eigenständig sinnvoll ist und mit den gefragten Worten anfängt. Begründungen kann ich m.E. immer mitten in einen Satz setzen.

Comment: Ich sollte vielleicht ergänzen, dass die Pedanterie bei mündlich/schriftlich teils in meinem Trotz begründet ist. So gibt es höchstrichterliche Urteile, wonach etwas, dass die Schriftform erfordert, von einer Seite Schreibmaschine erfüllt sein kann, von einer Email aber nicht. Umgekehrt hat, glaube ich, schon eine Tonbandaufnahme als Schrift gegolten, da bin ich aber unsicher. Abseits juristischen Zwangs sehe ich aber keinen Sinn darin. Und mit nämlich Sätze zu beginnen habe ich auch wenig Skrupel, wenn das meine innere Stimme reflektiert. Aber dann ist es wohl das, was Duden mündlich nennt.

Comment: @userunknown: Nun, ja, die juristische Sichtweise habe ich hier völlig ausgeblendet. MIr ging es um das "unjuristische pralle Leben". Denn ein Jurist fragt nicht unbedingt, ob eine Schadensersatzforderung dem gesunden Menschenverstand entspricht, sondern ob die zur Forderungszeit bestehenden Gesetzlage einen Anspruch erlauben. Erst nach dem Ob geht die Frage zum Wieviel. Und all das Fallbezogen. Und dann haben nur ähnliche Urteile höherer Instanzen in direkter Kette Bindungskraft... ja.